# Is it correct way to create separate layout file for supporting different screens?

Tags: android

I am fresher in android and i am starting my first app in android. I have login page for that i have created separate layout file for supporting different screens. here my question is that, is this perfect way to create separate layout file and can I optimize this layout for supporting diff screens. is there another way to create layout for supporting diff screens.

Following is my layout structure

```
res   
      layout
         activity_login
      layout-land
      layout-large
      layout-large-land
      layout-small
      layout-small-land     
      layout-xlarge
      layout-xlarge-land
      values
          styles.xml
          dimen.xml
      values-large
          styles.xml
          dimen_large.xml
      values-large-land
          styles.xml
          dimen_large_land.xml  
      .
      .
      .
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you are correct. You can create separate layout for different screens. Just go through this once : [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: just a quick tip that you don't have to create all those folders. Usually I start doing just the `layout` and only if really necessary I use some other (very common to use are land and small) (small devices always give problems)